# Can I edit a symmetry threshold? Or is that not the issue here?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, proportional-editing

I'm sorry to ask a very simple question, I come from Maya so my blender knowledge isn't great. I'm trying to edit a mesh with proportional editing- not sculpt mode as I need to edit multiple objects at once. I'm also trying to do it with symmetry enabled. WITHOUT a symmetry modifier, as I am editing a pre-existing mesh. I've ensured the model is perfectly symmetrical using the mirror tool etc and individually, all vertices look just about fine. But as soon as I begin using the proportional editing tool, it's like vertices get "left behind". I included a GIF to hopefully show what I mean. It's only ever on the opposite side of the mesh ie. the mirrored side. I've messed around with topology mirror vs non, and the strange thing is, in sculpt mode it works perfectly, but again I can't use sculpt mode as I want to edit the lashes at the same time as the tearline etc. I apologise for being such a beginner and asking a question that is probably very simple!
Also: I've noticed this on a lot of meshes I've worked with in the past, not just this project.

I was hoping there would be some way to somewhat alter the symmetry threshold or something. Like a way to define what vertices are symmetrical if within a distance of 0.001 instead of exact? Sorry, my wording isn't great!

any solutions would be greatly appreciated as I've struggled with this for so long that I had previously settled on just, suffering with it.

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to not use the mirror modifier? Coz else you can just delete one side and then use the mirror modifier. I don't know about why they are being left out like that though.

Comment: Maybe there shape keys on those eyelids? Without seeing your Blend file it's purely guesswork. If possible just save a Blend file with the head aand eyelashes in it and share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.